# Vue.js and Pouch - PouchDB is not a constructor

Tags: vue.js, vuex, pouchdb

Am building a simple Vue project to get to grips with simple store (vuex) and then using PouchDB. I am hitting an odd error and am struggling to see 
where to go next

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb')
import EntryForm from '@/components/EntryForm.vue'
import DisplayText from '@/components/DisplayText.vue'

export default {
  name: 'entryform',
  components: {
    EntryForm,
    DisplayText
  },

  data() {
    return {
      db: [],
      remote: [],
      stepfwd: [],
      stepback: [],
      newMutation: true
    }
  },
  created() {
    //window.db or this.db does it matter ?
    this.db = new PouchDB('icecream')
    this.remote = 'http://localhost:5984/icecream'
    this.db.sync(this.remote, { live: true, retry: true })

    //any mutations are put into the stepfwd array and put into the db array
    this.$store.subscribe(mutation => {
      if (mutation.type !== CLEAR_STATE) {
        this.stepfwd.push(mutation)
        this.db.push(mutation)
      }
      if (this.newMutation) {
        this.stepback = []
      }
    })
  }
```

Any helpers much appreciated.

all the branch code can be found here for review
https://gitlab.adamprocter.co.uk/adamprocter/simplevuestore/tree/pouchdb

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: PouchDB is not a constructor.

Comment: Try `import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'`

Comment: thank you, it was that simple I thought as I imported at main.js it was everywhere. re-writing the whole thing now as well as I should be using pouch in the store.js for the live data